# The answer is... What?

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

**Here's a small poem. See if you can find the answer! This is just a small riddle-type-thing that shouldn't be too hard for someone to solve! And yes, all the information that you need to solve this is available! Also, make sure to explain how you got the answer because that's pretty important! Anyways, the riddle-type-thing starts now:**

> *Enter it,
>
>   Violently running,
>
>   Every single time,
>
>   Running for my life,
>
>   Yawning deeply, very tired, it stopped
>
>   .........Waiting
>
>   Softly it creeps, once again,
>
>   Ever so softly,
>
>   Coming, It's coming,
>
>   Oh so softly,
>
>   No, it cannot be,
>
>   Deadly once again, rising,
>
>   .........Waiting
>
>   Look in it...
>
>   Editing it...
>
>   Turning around,
>
>   Tag is wrong, tag is right,
>
>   Entering, my hand is slipping,
>
>   Realized I'm back in it.*

**Hint:** Some lines are useless, the ones in the text, and some are clues for what to do next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in the source you'll see extra text at the bottom. Taking every second letter gives you "THE ANSWER IS PADLOCK".

Comment: Yes! You did it! Sorry for the very late confirmation, but this is right, good job!

Comment: The source of what? I don't get it...

Comment: @AnthonyGarcia click "edit" underneath the question, then you can see the "source", which is the raw text that Xandawesome typed. There's a message there at the bottom that doesn't appear on this page.

Comment: wow how did you think to look at the source?

Answer (score 5):

Partial answer?

> EVERY SECOND LETTER is spelled out as an acrostic, but I can't figure out how it applies. Taking every second letter of the text doesn't produce anything recognisable.

Comment: You're on the right track!